# Derviation of group velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, dispersion, phase-velocity

I am working thru a derivation of the [group velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) formula and I get to this stage:
$$y=2A\cos\left(x\frac{\Delta K}{2} -t\frac{\Delta \omega}{2}\right)\sin( \bar k x-\bar \omega t)$$
Then all the derivations I have seen say that $\frac{\Delta \omega}{\Delta K} $ is the group velocity. I know mathematically why this is a velocity but what I don't get is why do we know that this is the group velocity rather then the phase velocity and that $\frac{\bar \omega}{\bar k}$ is the phase velocity and not the group velocity?

Answer (score 7):

Consider a wave

$$A = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} a(k) e^{i(kx-\omega t)} \ dk,$$

where $a(k)$ is the amplitude of the kth wavenumber, and $\omega=\omega(k)$ is the frequency, related to $k$ via a dispersion relation. Note, if we wanted to track a wave, with wavenumber $k$, with constant phase, we would see that this occurs when $kx=\omega t$, i.e. $x/t = \omega/k = c$, with $c$ the $\textbf{phase}$ velocity.

We would like to know the speed at which the envelope $|A|$ is traveling.

For $\textbf{narrow banded}$ waves, the angular frequency $\omega$ can be approximated via the taylor expansion around a central wavenumber $k_o$, i.e.

$$\omega(k) = \omega(k_o) + \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k} (k-k_o) + \mathcal{O}((k-k_o)^2),$$

where the scale of the bandwidth is quantified by the small parameter $(k-k_o)$. Therefore, we can rewrite $A$ as

$$A \approx e^{-i(\omega(k_o)t-k_o\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k}t)} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} a(k) e^{ik(x-\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k} t)} \ dk.$$

Therefore

$$|A| = \left| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} a(k) e^{ik(x-\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k} t)} \ dk \right|,$$

which says that the envelope, $|A|$, travels at speed $\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k}$, i.e. $$|A(x,t)| = |A(x-c_g t,0)|,$$ where we have defined $$c_g \equiv \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k}.$$

The [group velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) has dynamical significance, as it is the velocity at which the energy travels.

Comment: You are missing an important $|_{k = k_0}$ to specify that the group velocity is evaluated at the central wavenumber.

Answer (score 3):

## **Definitions**

Before we begin, we should define some terms and parameters/functions that will be used later:

**Wave Number:**  $\equiv$ effectively the number of wave [crests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crest_(physics)) (i.e., anti-node of local maximum) per unit length $\leftrightharpoons$ ``density'' of waves $\rightarrow$ $\boldsymbol{\kappa}$ $=$ $\boldsymbol{\kappa}\left(\omega,\textbf{x},t\right)$ in general

**Wave Frequency:**  $\equiv$ effectively the number of wave crests crossing position $\mathbf{x}$ per unit time $\leftrightharpoons$ ``flux'' of waves $\rightarrow$ $\omega$ $=$ $\omega\left(\boldsymbol{\kappa},\textbf{x},t\right)$ in general

**Wave Phase:**  $\equiv$ position on a wave cycle between a crest and a trough (i.e., anti-node of local minimum) $\rightarrow$ $\phi$ $=$ $\phi\left(\textbf{x},t\right)$ in general

## **Phase and Continuity**

Then, we can define an elementary solution to periodic wave equations as:
$$
  \psi\left( \mathbf{x}, t \right) = \mathcal{A} \ e^{ {\displaystyle i\left( \boldsymbol{\kappa} \cdot \mathbf{x} - \omega t \right) } }
$$
where $\mathcal{A}$ is the wave [amplitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude) and, in general, can be a function of $\boldsymbol{\kappa}$ and/or $\omega$, but we will assume constant for now.  Let us assume that a [*dispersion relation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_relation), $\omega$ $=$ $\mathcal{W}\left( \boldsymbol{\kappa}, \textbf{x}, t \right)$, exists and may be solved for positive real roots.  In general, there will be multiple solutions to the dispersion relation, where each solution is referred to as different *modes*.  The term in the exponent is known as the [*wave phase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_(waves)), given by:
$$
  \phi\left( \mathbf{x}, t \right) = \boldsymbol{\kappa}\left( \omega, \mathbf{x}, t \right) \cdot \mathbf{x}  -  \omega\left( \boldsymbol{\kappa}, \mathbf{x}, t \right) \ t + \phi{\scriptstyle_{o}}
$$
Because $\phi\left(\textbf{x},t\right)$ results from solutions of the wave equation, its derivatives must satisfy the dispersion relation through the following:
$$
  - \frac{ \partial \phi\left( \mathbf{x}, t \right) }{ \partial t } = \mathcal{W}\left( \frac{ \partial \phi\left( \mathbf{x}, t \right) }{ \partial \mathbf{x} }, \mathbf{x}, t \right)
$$
and we can see from the equation for $\phi\left(\textbf{x},t\right)$ that the following is true:
$$
\begin{align}
  \boldsymbol{\kappa} & = \frac{ \partial \phi\left( \mathbf{x}, t \right) }{ \partial \mathbf{x} }  \\
  \omega & = - \frac{ \partial \phi\left( \mathbf{x}, t \right) }{ \partial t }
\end{align}
$$
We also know that $\partial^{2} \phi$/$\partial \mathbf{x} \partial t$ $=$ $\partial^{2} \phi$/$\partial t \partial \mathbf{x}$, therefore:
$$
\begin{align}
  \frac{ \partial^{2} \phi }{ \partial t \partial \mathbf{x} } - \frac{ \partial^{2} \phi }{ \partial \mathbf{x} \partial t } & = 0  \\
  & = \frac{ \partial \boldsymbol{\kappa} }{ \partial t } - \frac{ - \partial \omega }{ \partial \mathbf{x} } = 0  \\
  & = \frac{ \partial \boldsymbol{\kappa} }{ \partial t } + \frac{ \partial \omega }{ \partial \mathbf{x} } = 0  \\
  & = \frac{ \partial \boldsymbol{\kappa} }{ \partial t } + \nabla \omega = 0
\end{align}
$$
One can see that this final form looks similar to a [*continuity equation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation), so long as $\boldsymbol{\kappa}$ $\leftrightharpoons$ *density* of the waves, and $\omega$ $\leftrightharpoons$ [*flux*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux) of the waves.

## **Phase Velocity**

From the above relations, we can see that on *contours* of constant $\phi\left(\textbf{x},t\right)$, we are sitting on local wave crests (i.e., *phase fronts*) where $\boldsymbol{\kappa}$ is orthogonal to these *contours*.  These phase fronts move parallel to $\boldsymbol{\kappa}$ at a speed, $\mathbf{V}_{\phi}$, known as the [*phase velocity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity).  The general form for this speed is given by:
$$
  \mathbf{V}_{\phi} \equiv \frac{ \mathcal{W}\left( \boldsymbol{\kappa}, \mathbf{x}, t \right) }{ \kappa } \boldsymbol{\hat{\kappa}}
$$

## **Group Velocity**

We can rearrange our continuity equation by multiplying by unity to get:
$$
\begin{align}
  \frac{ \partial \boldsymbol{\kappa} }{ \partial t } + \frac{ \partial \omega }{ \partial \mathbf{x} } \cdot \frac{ \partial \boldsymbol{\kappa} }{ \partial \boldsymbol{\kappa} } & = 0  \\
  \frac{ \partial \boldsymbol{\kappa} }{ \partial t } + \frac{ \partial \omega }{ \partial \boldsymbol{\kappa} } \cdot \frac{ \partial \boldsymbol{\kappa} }{ \partial \mathbf{x} } & = 0  \\
  \frac{ \partial \boldsymbol{\kappa} }{ \partial t } + \left( \mathbf{V}_{g} \cdot \nabla \right) \boldsymbol{\kappa} & = 0
\end{align}
$$
where $\mathbf{V}_{g}$ is called the [*group velocity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity), where we note that:
$$
\frac{ \partial \omega }{ \partial \mathbf{x} } = \frac{ \partial \mathcal{W}\left( \boldsymbol{\kappa}, \mathbf{x}, t \right) }{ \partial \boldsymbol{\kappa} } \cdot \frac{ \partial \boldsymbol{\kappa} }{ \partial \mathbf{x} } + \frac{ \partial \mathcal{W}\left( \boldsymbol{\kappa}, \mathbf{x}, t \right) }{ \partial \mathbf{x} }
$$
which shows that $\partial \mathcal{W}$/$\partial \boldsymbol{\kappa}$ $=$ $\left( \partial \omega / \partial \boldsymbol{\kappa} \right){\scriptstyle_{\textbf{x}}}$ $\Rightarrow$ *different $\boldsymbol{\kappa}$'s propagate with velocity $\mathbf{V}_{g}$*.  In other words, *$\mathbf{V}_{g}$ is the propagation velocity for $\kappa$* and *$\mid$$\mathcal{A}$$\mid^{2}$ propagates with velocity $\mathbf{V}_{g}$*.

Thus, an observer moving with the phase fronts (crests) moves at $\mathbf{V}_{\phi}$, but they observe the local wavenumber and frequency to change in time $\Rightarrow$ neighboring phase fronts (crests) move away from the observer in this frame.  In contrast, for an observer moving with $\mathbf{V}_{g}$, they observe constant local [wavenumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber) and [frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency) (with respect to time), but phase fronts (crests) continuously move past the observer in this frame.

## **References**

Whitham, G. B. (1999), *Linear and Nonlinear Waves*, New York, NY: John Wiley & Sons, Inc.; ISBN:0-471-35942-4.

Comment: +1 for any whitham reference i see on this site :-) @Joseph although this ray theory derivation is certainly legitimate, and interesting, it is kinematic. i think the dynamic approach also should be studied in some detail to understand the concepts at play.

Comment: @NickP - I see you study water waves.  I suppose I could have thrown in a Longuet-Higgins and Stewart reference as well ;)

Comment: now we're talking!

Answer (score 0):

The frequency $\omega$ can be hight in a wave packet, but the envelope motion may be slow. The latter is determined with the $\cos(...)$; that is why they call it a group velocity. It is a velocity of displacement of the packet as a whole. There muct be applets on internet to show how a wave packet moves.

Comment: How do we know it is determined by $cos(...)$ though??

Comment: @Joseph: Because the $\sin(...)$ is a carrier wave by definition. A time-dependent factor at it is a wave envelope, by definition too.