# Derivation of the group velocity

Tags: optics, waves, refraction, approximations, phase-velocity

I know that the group velocity of a light pulse is defined as

$$\begin{split}v_g&=v_p\left(1+\frac{\lambda}{n}\frac{dn}{d\lambda}\right)\\
&=\frac{c}{n}\left(1+\frac{\lambda}{n}\frac{dn}{d\lambda}\right).\end{split} \tag{1}$$

On the other hand, it is also defined as

$$\begin{split}v_g &= \frac{c}{\left(n-\lambda\frac{dn}{d\lambda}\right)}\\
&=\frac{c}{n}\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\frac{dn}{d\lambda}\right)^{-1}.\end{split}\tag{2}$$

That leads to the equation

$$0=\frac{\lambda^2}{n^2}\left(\frac{dn}{d\lambda}\right)^2.\tag{3}$$

After neither $\lambda$ nor $n$ is $0$, does that mean that $\left(\frac{dn}{d\lambda}\right)^2=0$? And how can I justify that?
Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity#Other_expressions
Alternative explanation: Wiki is crap?

Comment: I don't see where in that article it gives $\frac{c}{n}\bigl(1 - \frac{\lambda}{n}\frac{\mathrm{d}n}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\bigr)^{-1}$. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Well, if $\lambda/n\ dn/d\lambda$ is small the two are equivalent to first order in this small parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Derviation of group velocity](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143696/)

Comment: @honeste_vivere: not so. Despite its title, that other Q is about deriving the _definition_ of the group velocity.

Comment: Comment to the post (v5): OP is not quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity#Other_expressions) accurately. Eq. (2) should be  $v_g=v_p \left(1-\frac{\lambda_0}{n}\frac{dn}{d\lambda_0}\right)^{-1}$, where $\lambda_0$ is the **vacuum** wavelength.

Comment: @Qmechanic: I noticed that now, too. What can I do to improve the question accordingly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first equation correctly states that
$$
v_g = \frac{c}{n}\left(1 + \frac{\lambda}{n}\frac{dn}{d\lambda}\right).
$$
But if you look at the wikipedia page that you linked to, you'll see that the second equation should read
$$
v_g = \frac{c}{n}\left(1 - \frac{\lambda_0}{n}\frac{dn}{d\lambda_0}\right)^{-1},
$$
where $\lambda_0$ is the wavelength in vacuum, and
$$
n = \frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda},
$$
where $\lambda$ is the wavelength in the medium. The second equation can be derived from the first as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
v_g &= \frac{c}{n}\left(1 + \frac{\lambda}{n}\frac{dn}{d\lambda}\right)\\
&= \frac{c}{n}\left[1 + \frac{\lambda}{n}\left(\frac{d\lambda}{dn}\right)^{-1}\right]\\
&= \frac{c}{n}\left[1 + \frac{\lambda_0}{n^2}\left(\frac{d(\lambda_0/n)}{dn}\right)^{-1}\right]\\
&= \frac{c}{n}\left[1 + \frac{\lambda_0}{n^2}\left(-\frac{\lambda_0}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n}\frac{d\lambda_0}{dn}\right)^{-1}\right]\\
&= \frac{c}{n}\left[1 + \left(-1 + \frac{n}{\lambda_0}\frac{d\lambda_0}{dn}\right)^{-1}\right]\\
&= \frac{c}{n}\left[\frac{n}{\lambda_0}\frac{d\lambda_0}{dn}\left(-1 + \frac{n}{\lambda_0}\frac{d\lambda_0}{dn}\right)^{-1}\right]\\
&= \frac{c}{n}\left[\left(-\frac{\lambda_0}{n}\left(\frac{d\lambda_0}{dn}\right)^{-1} + 1\right)^{-1}\right]\\
&= \frac{c}{n}\left(1 - \frac{\lambda_0}{n}\frac{dn}{d\lambda_0}\right)^{-1}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Group velocity, for any kind of wave, is *defined* as $$\boxed{v_g=\frac{\mathrm dω}{\mathrm dk}}.$$

Phase velocity is defined as $v_p=\dfrac ωk$, and refraction index as $n=\dfrac c{v_p}$. So $ω=c\,\dfrac kn$. Hence,
$$\mathrm dω=c\left(\frac{\mathrm dk}n-\frac{k\,\mathrm dn}{n^2}\right)=\frac{c\,\mathrm dk}{n}\left(1-\frac kn\frac{\mathrm dn}{\mathrm dk}\right).$$

Given that $k=\dfrac{2π}λ$, $\dfrac{\mathrm dk}k=-\dfrac{\mathrm dλ}λ$ (logarithmic differentiation), so that
$$v_g=\frac{\mathrm dω}{\mathrm dk}=\frac cn\left(1+\frac λn\frac{\mathrm dn}{\mathrm dλ}\right).$$

Edit: this demonstration shows the first equation you cite is correct, the second is not.

Comment: My point is that I do not have `k` in the first equation, but `$\lambda$` instead

Comment: Please read the *whole* answer. Group velocity is defined as I stated, period. k=2π/λ so you can reformulate this with λ if you like, vg=-λ²/2π*dω/dλ.

Comment: That means that Wikipedia is apparently incorrect...

Comment: Edit 2: Found a solution for both possibilities, your answer might need an edit.

Comment: The group velocity is a vector, defined as:$$\mathbf{V}_{g} = \partial_{\mathbf{k}} \ \omega\left(\mathbf{k}\right) = \frac{c}{\omega} \left[ \hat{\mathbf{k}} \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial n} + \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \frac{1}{n} \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \theta} \right]$$

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found an answer on my own:
For the first definition the answer from L. Levrel is sufficient. For the second definition one has to follow the following set of equations:
$$\begin{split}
\frac{1}{v_g}&=\frac{dk}{d\omega}\\
&=c^{-1}\left(n+\omega\frac{dn}{d\omega}\right)\\
&=c^{-1}\left(n-\lambda\cdot\frac{dn}{d\lambda}\right)\\
\Rightarrow v_g&=\frac{c}{n\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\frac{dn}{d\lambda}\right)}
\end{split}$$
which is what I wanted to get.
How to get from $\omega$ to $\lambda$: 
$$\begin{split} \omega&=\frac{2\pi c}{\lambda}\\
\Rightarrow\frac{dn}{d\omega}&=\frac{dn}{d\lambda}\frac{d\lambda}{d\omega}\\
&=\frac{dn}{d\lambda}\frac{d\lambda}{d\frac{2\pi c}{\lambda}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi c}\frac{dn}{d\lambda}\frac{d\lambda}{d\frac{1}{\lambda}}\\
&=-\frac{\lambda^2}{2\pi c}\frac{dn}{d\lambda}\\
&=-\frac{\lambda}{\omega}\frac{dn}{d\lambda}\end{split}$$

Comment: I'm curious to read how you get line 3 from line 2, that is, how you change variable $ω$ into $λ$. Remember that $ω=2πc/nλ$. Your answer might need an edit (or deletion) :-)

Comment: @L.Levrel: I added an explanation, I hope that helps.  In general I had the impression that $\omega$ is not influenced by the refractive index, but the phase velocity is (by $v_p = \frac{\omega}{k_0\cdot n}$)

Comment: Suggestion to the answer (v2): Replace all appearances of $\lambda$ with the vacuum wavelength $\lambda_0$.

Comment: @L.Levrel: Do you have a source for $\omega=\frac{2\pi c}{n\lambda}$? I could not find anything for that...

Comment: By definition, $v_p=ω/k$. Since $v_p=c/n$ by definition of $n$, you find $ω=kc/n$. Of course $λ$ depends on $n$. See also Pulsar's answer.