# Group index derivation issue

Tags: frequency, wavelength, dispersion

How do I derive the expression for the group index $N_g$ as below

$$N_g=n-\lambda\frac{dn}{d\lambda}$$

using the Cauchy dispersion relation below?
$$n=n_{-2}(hf)^{-2}+n_0+n_2(hf)^2+n_4(hf)^4$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [You don't need Cauchy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/249264).